# Exact categories which are not additive

Tags: homological-algebra, ct.category-theory

There are various notions of exact categories ([nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+category)). In a lecture I've seen the following definition of an exact category, which is basically (exact) = (abelian) − (additive):

A category $C$ is called **exact** if a) it contains a zero object, b) every morphism has a kernel and a cokernel, c) the canonical morphism $\operatorname{coim}(f) \to \operatorname{im}(f)$ is an isomorphism for every morphism $f$.

So for example, the category of pointed sets is an exact category in this sense. I think also  the category of pointed compactly generated hausdorff spaces is an example.

**Questions**: 1) Which theorems and constructions of homological algebra carry over from abelian categories to exact categories in the above sense? 2)  Where can I find literature about these categories? I can only find some about the other definitions.

Comment: I am not familiar with this notion of exact category (and my gut feeling is that it isn't a very useful notion, although I would welcome being shown otherwise). But is the category of pointed compactly generated Hausdorff spaces an example? What if you take $f$ to be the identity function from the real line with the discrete topology to the real line with its standard topology? 

Comment: Ok. There are kernels and cokernels, but c) is not satisfied. Perhaps the same problem with compact spaces.

Comment: The notion of exact category which I have seen (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_category) is different --- the typical examples of exact categories are the category of vector bundles, or the category of filtered vector spaces. Both don't satisfy your definition.

Comment: @Sasha: I know that and mentioned it in the first line of my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These categories are called Puppe-exact or p-exact categories.  See paragraph 1.1, of *Jordan-Hölder, modularity and distributivity in non-commutative algebra*,  by Francis Borceux and Marco Grandis (JPAA **208** (2007), 665-689 doi:[10.1016/j.jpaa.2006.03.004](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2006.03.004)), for non-abelian examples.  And see the papers of Marco Grandis (e.g. *On the categorical foundations of homological and homotopical algebra* ([Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1992__33_2_135_0/))) and Mitchell's book “Theory of categories” for homological results in this context (as a general rule, all homological lemmas non involving direct products hold).

Comment: Dear Mathieu, I think what Martin proposes is not necessarily Puppe-exact. For example, the category of pointed sets is not Puppe-exact. The epimorphisms are not cokernels in general.

Comment: Since the answer was accepted, I assume the OP was happy with it.